# Trying To Install Tag Manager on 1.9 But It Won't Fire On Front End

Tags: magento-1.9, google-tag-manager

I've been trying to get Tag Manager to fire on a client's Magento 1.9 website but it won't appear in the front end.

I have placed it in the **`Config->General->Design->HTML Head/Footer->Miscellaneous Scripts sections`**, underneath their existing Zendesk and CrazyEgg scripts, cleared all cache, and made sure that Magento is in developer mode to check the JS settings.

Zendesk's and CrazyEgg's scripts continue to show on the front end, but the GTM code I added is not being pulled through. I know I am missing something, so if you have any suggestions, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Yes, it is something related to the script not being rendered over the page. It might be some tag issue or some other hands scripts are blocking... So if you can share all the scripts which are saved in the Miscellaneous textarea you can share I will look at this.

Comment: Hi Dotsquares,

Thank you for the response!

There are only 3 in there. The standard Zendesk chat script, the standard CrazyEgg script, and then the GTM script.

Comment: Could you try to remove commenting code if exists inside the scripts?

Comment: Just removed all commenting code, flushed all cache, and on the front end, it still has the commenting code in the source code. So it's definitely not updating cache somewhere, but I am not sure where... Thanks for the responses so far!

Comment: If you have created a new user account and want to grant them specific permissions related to administration, you will need to share that information with me. Without this information, it can be difficult to solve any issues related to these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the GTM code is not being blocked by any ad-blockers or other browser extensions. You can do this by temporarily disabling any such extensions and checking if the GTM code appears on the front end

Comment: Hi Harun, and thanks for the response. I have tested it both on Chrome with and without extensions active, as well as a clean install of Edge and Firefox. Unfortunately, no luck.

Comment: Are you using GTM debugging tool?
I think this tool will help you.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that I have used the debugging tool, which cannot find the GTM tag either. It also does not appear in the source code on the front end. It's like it's a caching issue but there is no additional cache I know of to clear

Comment: Are you cleared DNS cache also?

Comment: Hi Harun :) I've just double-checked by clearing the DNS cache in Chrome, as I think I forgot to do that earlier. And still no change. :D Thank you for the help so far!

Comment: Which hosting service are you using?